# Programmatically set Master page for settings.aspx page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

How can I set the application master page specifically for settings.aspx and not for the whole site in `SharePoint 2010` dynamically using `asp.net` and `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to [create an HttpModule](http://spmenia.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-apply-httpmodule-in-sharepoint-2010/).